# Is it permissible to shave for business purposes after Shiva but during shloshim?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, employment, shaving

Is one allowed to shave after *shiva* (7 days of mourning for deceased) if one is concerned about seeing clients at work? Most authorities say that one should wait 30 days before shaving.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Keep in mind that we [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) here. You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. Please consult rabbinic advice before implementing anything you learn here. Hope to see you around!

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=633&st=&pgnum=78 permits regular shaving after 3 months after a parent for those who have business dealings with non-Jews.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.dinonline.org/2013/02/03/shaving-in-shloshim-for-parnassah/) should answer your question:

> The custom of refraining from haircuts during the sheloshim is
>   generally applied even to shaving, but there is some room to
>   distinguish between them, because shaving (which is done daily) does
>   not involve the festive nature of a haircut.
>
> In addition, it is possible that reasons of losing one’s parnasah will
>   be sufficient to waive the custom, as we find in a number of poskim
>   concerning Sefiras Ha-Omer (see Kaf Ha-Chaim 493:19; Iggros Moshe
>   Orach Chaim 4:102).